# How can a JavaScript evaluation return an object?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I don't expect you to understand what was *meant* with this piece of code:

```
var columnOverrides = rowMetadata &&
    rowMetadata.columns &&
    (rowMetadata.columns[column.id] || rowMetadata.columns[getColumnIndex(column.id)]);

return columnOverrides.formatter;
```

But syntactically, how can the evaluation of a logical expression return an object?

Comment: `||` is often meant as a "default" operator in this kind of situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JavaScript, `a && b` evaluates `a` first. If `a` is a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) value, then it returns `a`, otherwise it returns `b`. `a || b` works the same; if `a` is truthy, return `a`, else return `b`.

This can lead to some really nice and concise yet clear code (once you understand it) like "get the first non-null value":

```
var a = null;
var b = null;
var c = 5;
var d = "Hello";

alert(a && b && c && d); // 5
```

Or easy cross-browser events:

```
var f = window.addEventListener || window.attachEvent || (function() {});
f.call(window, 'load', function() {
     alert('Loaded!');
}, false);
```

Comment: Really nice examples, especially the second one - it's blowing my mind.

Answer (score 8):

In JavaScript `&&` and `||` don't necessarily return true or false. They return one of their arguments.

- `a || b` is roughly equivalent to `a ? a : b`.
- `a && b` is roughly equivalent to `a ? b : a`.

More information can be found here:

- http://www.ejball.com/EdAtWork/2005/02/19/JavaScriptBooleanOperators.aspx

Answer (score 2):

As the question was answered - I think there is a but in this code - if `rowMetadata` is `null` or `undefined` or such it will break, and if you're using `&&` it IS a possibility. Just a heads up.

last line should be also:

```
return columnOverrides && columnOverrides.formatter;
```

Comment: Jesus, you have some serious skills! In fact the original `return` was quite more complex -I cut it down for making my question clearer- and indeed it used shortcircuiting that way.